# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to handle the paste event and trying to convert rich text into plain text, I have a content editable (dynamically created) div inside a container with id `main`

```
$("#main").on("paste","div",function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var clipboarddata =  event.clipboardData ||window.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData;                  
  var onlytext = clipboarddata.getData('text/plain');
  document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, onlytext);
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined

I think `event.clipboarddata` is not working, my browser supports clipboard API. i am copying the text and pasting it into div. So clipboard should have some value

Can someone explain why I `clipboardData` is undefined

Comment: Note that in `event.originalEvent.clipboarddata` the "d" in "data" should be "D".

Comment: @pointy yes ,i correct it, But still same error

Comment: OK, well, understand that security considerations may prevent your code from gaining access to the clipboard data. Your code should check to make sure that there *is* data before assuming it can be used.

Comment: @pointy any solution for that

Comment: Yes. Check the value to make sure it isn't defined. If the browser won't give you the data, there's nothing you can do to force it.

Comment: You can try `var t = e.originalEvent.clipboardData ? e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text/plain") : window.clipboardData.getData("text");` originalEvent is jquery and since jquery is supposedly not required for ui-select, this reference to originalEvent should be removed completely for other fix e.g. `var t = e.clipboardData ? e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain") : window.clipboardData.getData("text");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For latest browser Chrome below line will work.

```
var clipboarddata = window.event.clipboardData.getData('text');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#main").on("paste",function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var clipboarddata =  window.event.clipboardData.getData('text');    
      console.log("paste value" + clipboarddata);
      $('#pasteData').text(clipboarddata);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="main" name="first_name" value="" maxlength="100" />
<div>paste value :  <span id="pasteData"><span></div>
```

Comment: No, it won't. Firefox doesn't have `window.event`, and even if it does it's not always the case that `event.clipboardData` is available. Your code is essentially exactly what the OP already has.

Comment: Could you please tell your browser version

Comment: i have Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit) and it's working perfectly fine, could you please share the exact code and error, so i can try in my machine thanks

Comment: clipboard is accessible on localhost , but on real site or application, javascript is not allowed to access the clipboard.The "security setting" to which it is referring is the fact that JavaScript executing in a web browser does not have access to your clipboard

Comment: what do you mean javascript doesn't have access to your clipboard, javascript runs in local machine (individual browser and does have the access to the clipboard data) above code snippet works fine, kindly try to run it.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: This is *WHY* you are getting the error. Fixing the bug is a different matter and one that would need more information from you.**

The reason you are getting the error is because when you use OR operators on variable assignment, it will always assign the value of the last one, even if it is `null`, `false`, or `undefined`.

Basically, it goes like this

```
if (event.clipboardData != null/false/undefined) { //ignore the incorrectness of the truncation
  var clipboarddata = event.clipboardData;
} else if (window.clipboardData != null/false/undefined) {
  var clipboarddata = window.clipboardData;
} else { //default to the last option even if it is null/false/undefined
  var clipboarddata = event.originalEvent.clipboardData;
}
```

So since all three are `undefined`, you get the value of `event.originalEvent.clipboardData` which is `undefined` assigned to the variable. Hence the error on the next line.

Comment: yes u are correct , but why i am getting undefined , i am copying text, so cliboard should provide a valid value

Comment: @beginner - There is not enough information in the OP to give an answer. `console.log` your various outputs and vars, look at that to figure out where it is breaking. Drop event listeners on all your actions and `console.log` those. Back up the chain of events until you find the error.